# What is the purpose of the "master" parameter in the tkinter Variable class/subclasses?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I've been looking for some more detailed information regarding the `Variable` subclasses in tkinter, namely `BooleanVar`, `DoubleVar`, `IntVar`, and `StringVar`. I'm hoping someone with broader knowledge can point me in the right direction.

Given the constructor:
`tkinter.Variable(master=None, value=None, name=None)`
I'm curious what the utility of the `master` parameter is for these classes. I understand that it's equivalent to the `master` parameter for other tkinter widgets, but I'm not sure I understand how it affects these variable classes specifically; it's a bit more intuitive when the widget is the child of a given class.

I typically ignore this value, as I understand that (assuming this is in my root class that inherits from `Tk`) `self.var = tk.StringVar()` is equivalent to `self.var = tk.StringVar(self)`, or `self.var = tk.StringVar(None)`. Should I be including this? Is it providing some functionality I would otherwise be missing? I'm not necessarily looking for "What is the best practice here", but rather an explanation of the intended use.

Any info is much appreciated!

*Here's a link to what little information I've been able to find, if anyone else is curious
[TkDocs - Variable](https://tkdocs.com/pyref/variable.html)*

Comment: It's useful when you have an application that opens multiple frames.

Comment: @Barmar But wouldn't all those frames be children of the root window anyway? I'm not saying I disagree, just genuinely curious!

Comment: The only time you absolutely have to use this parameter is if you have multiple instances of `Tk()` - if a Var isn't associated with the same instance as the widget that's trying to use it, it will silently fail.  But it's far easier to fix that kind of problem by using a single instance of `Tk()`, and use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: @jasonharper What I meant was multiple root windows.

Comment: @jasonharper That makes sense. I've only ever dealt with a single `Tk()` and a few `Toplevel()` children - I try to avoid multiple instances of `Tk()`, but this is good to know!

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, with multiple roots, it makes sense! But it seems to me that having multiple *root* windows is a bit oxymoronic, no?

Comment: Think of the root as like a browser window. Each root is its own, independent environment.

Comment: @Barmar That's a good analogy. What's a good use case for multiple root windows? I imagine they're all still bound to the same interpreter/application instance (again, like a browser)

Comment: Imagine you were writing a browser in Python. Each browser window could be a separate Tk instance, and it will prevent `Variable` instances from interfering with each other.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an instance of `Tk`, you are doing more than just creating a widget. For each instance, you are also creating an embedded Tcl interpreter. This tcl interpreter is where all of the widgets and variables and image objects exist. The objects within this interpreter are only available to that interpreter and cannot be shared with other interpreters.

If you create multiple instances of `Tk`, the `master` parameter lets you tell tkinter which interpreter each variable belongs to. Without it, the variables and widgets will be created in the interpreter of the first instance of `Tk`.

Comment: @JRiggles everything Bryan says makes since. I have leaned more from him than anyone else on this platform :)

Comment: @Mike-SMT Likewise - glad he puts up with the likes of me! ;)